# Getting HTML or JSON response from ajax call, Which is good?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a functionality in my project where I have implemented the search functionality.

On submitting the form via ajax, I need to show all the results in a division.

There are two ways I can do this.

1. Getting the JSON data as ajax response and bind it to the HTML elements.
2. I can also get the completely formatted HTML response from the ajax call and can directly bind it to the result div on the search page.

So which way is suggestible ?

Answer (score 4):

To make a service (server-side script) the most re-usable or even make it into an `API` - the suggested way is to return `JSON` data (converted from data models) to the front end, where using JavaScript you can populate the data to the `HTML`.

As for the `HTML` - you can certainly make the server return the response as `HTML` (setting the correct mime & content type in headers) but this gives the server control over the UI layer and the separation between the interface and the server/db is not balanced properly...

Answer (score 4):

Either option is fine, depending on your how much html there is and how much server-side processing you need to do on the HTML. If it is just a div and a value that needs to be inserted, then I say just go with JSON. The JSON approach will be more lightweight (consumes less bandwidth and keeps the role of the server as an API that is transferable to non web-page requests).

If you need to do a lot of server-side processing and assembling and what you are returning is really a sub-page, then you might consider html from the server. In this case have a partial html file that you read and send (inserting data where relevant) rather than building the html from strings on the fly. If you have a partial file, then you can edit and check it with standard html editors and you can see the html layout easily and it keeps the UI aspects separate from the business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd send it as JSON and build the HTML client side for a few reasons:

- The JSON payload would be lighter and therefore faster to send over the wire
- The API becomes more reusable (if you ever wanted to hook up additional clients that render differently etc.)
- If you build the HTML on the client side then it's probably easier to take advantage of templating libraries (e.g. JQuery Templates) or even better, directly binding the data to the UI (such as [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/))

Answer (score 0):

I always do the JSON response. To me it looks like a much more consistent and flexible way since you can return more data than only presentation. If you still want to return HTML you can also do it through a JSON response:

```
{
   error: false
   html: "<div>Done!</div>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd send it as a JSON response, too.

1. As suggested by emiolioicai in his code, with JSON you can easily handle errors. For example:

```
        {
           error: true 
           error-message: wrong parameters
        }
```

1. If you define your HTML client side, in the future you will be able to use the same AJAX request and customize HTML differently in another part of your website.

Comment: You can always put your HTML into a json value and still have your error handling values in there

Comment: yes, of course @Coulton :) it depends on the structure of your application: you can decide whether you prefer to define html in a specific view, different everytime, or put html into json and have a common view for error handling.